$\frac{a}{x},\frac{b}{y},\frac{c}{z}$ are in HP
If non-zero numbers $a,b,c,x,y$ and $z$ are such that $a,b,c$ are in AP, $x,y,z$ are in GP and $\frac{a}{x},\frac{b}{y},\frac{c}{z}$ are in HP then prove $|a|=|c|$.
I have been trying to solve this problem taking $x, y$ and $z$ as $x,xr,xr^2$ making it a quadratic in $r$. Equation I got is $a(a+c)r^2-acr+c(a+c)=0$ but it leads to no where. Please help

This is quite an interesting question. Where is it from?

It appeared in one of the coaching textbook FIITJEE GMP

Thanks. (I'm still thinking about the original question... it is tougher than it looks)

Stating the conclusion as $|a|=|c|$ makes no sense, because if $c = -a$ then $b=0$ which contradicts the hypothesis.  So the conclusion should simply be $a=c$.

The three conditions can be rewritten, with $\varepsilon=\pm1$:
$$b=\frac{a+c}2,\quad y=\varepsilon\sqrt{xz},\quad\frac xa+\frac zc=\frac{4\varepsilon\sqrt{xz}}{a+c}.$$
Letting $u:=\frac xa$ and $v:=\frac zc$, the third condition rewrites $u+v=\frac{4\varepsilon\sqrt{uvac}}{a+c}$, i.e.
$$\frac{(u+v)^2}{4uv}=\frac{4ac}{(a+c)^2}.$$

If we assume $ac>0$, the RHS is $\le1$ whereas the LHS is $\ge1$, hence both are equal to $1$, so $a=c$.
However, without this assumption, the claim is false. A counterexample is the following: $t$ being any of the two solutions of $$(t+1)^2=-4t,$$ take
$$c=z=1,\quad a=t,\quad x=t^2,\quad b=\frac{1+t}2,\quad y=-t.$$

